# Where is the latest 32-bit Chrome installer

Tags: google-chrome, 32-bit

When I opened Facebook earlier, I saw that I needed to update my Chrome browser because of security stuff. I am on Windows 7 32-bit with 1 GB of RAM (yes, 1 GB)

When I went to the Chrome page, the only Windows installer is a 64-bit one. Where can I find a 32-bit installer. Can somebody tell me where it is?

Comment: Even more obnoxious is that you can't seem to download a package for a completely different OS from that page either.

Comment: chrome doesnt support 32 bit but chromium does. find a chromium 32-bit build

Comment: You shouldn't use Chrome on a PC with less RAM. Firefox and Vivaldi are much less memory hungry @UğurGümüşhan the OP is using Windows

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that you need to force the page to the proper OS using the `platform` key in the query string.

[Chrome for Win32](https://www.google.com/chrome/?platform=win)

Answer (score 2):

The enterprise page has 32 bit MSI downloads for the latest version:

https://enterprise.google.com/chrome/chrome-browser/

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome](https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/) still has official support for the 32-bit architecture. In the image of chrome official download site below,you can find both 32-bit and 64-bit have the same latest version release number viz 89.0.4389.90
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -3):

Chrome no longer supports 32 Bit operating systems - this is True not only for Windows, but also for OSX and Linux.

The last Chrome Version for 32 Bit Windows is no longer safe to run.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: are you sure? there's a version "For Windows 10/8.1/8/7 32-bit" as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqQzc.png)